# price tag on image

Tags: html, image, css

How do I get a price tag on image (with pure CSS) like how is in this attached image?

I used

```
content:'';
    width:0px; height:0px; 
    position: absolute; left:194px; top:-20px;
    border:10px solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0,0,0,0.8) transparent;
```

but it didnt help!!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/xtCb9/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/hWnYa/)

Assuming you would have an image of the price tag in the 'tag' id div and then the image underneath it

EDIT

I've updated this now so you can have something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/hWnYa/2/) Where you can have the price in the div with it

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what results you currently get, except that it doesn't work. So maybe you should specifiy the problem further.

For creating triangles in CSS-only, you could look at this CSS-trick, but it doesn't allow for text or styles added to the triangle: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

If you want that, you should use transforms to get a similar result.